# Executions hangs up with no error after moving files to external jar

Tags: java, jar

I have develop a simple java program to run APDU commands. It is working fine.
The file structure is

```
/moc
   /omnikey
     --Applet.java
     --API.java
   /omnikey.api
   /omnikey.util
   ... another 3 more packages ...
```

Now, I want to extract all those extra packages to a new project and leave only the `omnikey` package (with `Applet.java` and `API.java`) to create a .jar with the needed functionality.

So I created a new project, copied all files, fixed the packages references and linked the external jars needed... and now it doesn't work...

The "new" file structure is like this

```
/apdu
    /apduservice
        /api
            ... files ...
        /util
           ... files ...

/moc
    /omnikey
       Applet.java
       API.java
```

For some reason, the execution hangs when I declare something from the apdu project. If I do

```
System.out.println("flag 1");
try {
    apduservice.api.MocService ser = new apduservice.api.MocService(null);
} catch (CardServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("flag 2");
```

I get no error trace and the output is `flag 1`. The execution doesn't stop until force it.

If I try the same thing with the previous configuration everything works.

```
System.out.println("flag 1");
try {
    omnikey.api.MocService ser = new apduservice.api.MocService(null);
} catch (CardServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("flag 2");

//output flag 1 and flag 2
```

I'm not sure where the error might be. I tried exporting the second project as jar, as runnable jar, reference it as a project inside Eclipse, and nothing, the same result. I've tried searching for a solution, but since I get no error, it's hard to know what to look for.

If someone could shed a light I'll be grateful.

PD: doesn't seem to be an Eclipse problem, I've referenced projects in other projects and it has work fine...
PD2: I'm not using Maven or anything like that to handle references. I rather not to, at least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to answer this since there's no logical reason for this to happen.

Solution:
change workspaces, open the two projects and link them. Eclipse was just having one of its days.